# How can I resolve this axios post request?

Tags: reactjs, post, axios

I am trying to send form data to the back end and see it visible in the server console, I am not getting any errors in the front end console when I submit the form but I do not see any sign that the information is being sent, where am I making the mistake?

```
 <Formik
                                initialValues={{
                                  firstName: "",
                                  lastName: "",
                                  email: "",
                                  Password: "",
                                  ConfirmPassword: "",
                                }}
                                validationSchema={SignupSchema}
                                // on submit handles here
                                onSubmit={async (values) => {
                                  console.log("logging click");
                                  const {
                                    firstName,
                                    lastName,
                                    email,
                                    Password,
                                    ConfirmPassword,
                                  } = values;
                                  const data = new FormData();

                                  data.append("firstName", firstName);
                                  data.append("lastName", lastName);
                                  data.append("email", email);
                                  data.append("Password", Password);
                               data.append("ConfirmPassword",ConfirmPassword);                        
                                  //   axios post requst to back end happens here

                                  const form = document.querySelector("form");
                                  if (form) {
                                    form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
                                      e.preventDefault();
                                      const FormData = new FormData(form);
                                      axios.post(
                                          "                                       
                                   "http://localhost:8080/api/admin/signup",
                                          FormData,
                                          {
                                            headers: {
                                              "Content-Type":
                                                "multipart/form-data",
                                            },
                                          }
                                        )
                                        .then((res) => {
                                          console.log(res);
                                        })
                                        .catch((err) => {
                                          console.log(err);
                                        });
                                    });
                                  }

                                  // same shape as initial values
                                }}
                              >
```

Comment: You don't even have an `URL` for your post request, `axios` must be in the below format: `axios.post(url[, data[, config]])`, check this: [Axios API](https://axios-http.com/docs/api_intro)

Comment: updated it, for some reason the updated url didn't show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the code is attempting to send the form data **twice** – once using the **axios.post** method and again using a separate event listener for the **form submission**. This might be causing confusion and issues with the request.

Try submitting the form directly using **axios.post** inside the **onSubmit** and remove the addListener that you are adding. Below is the updated code. Hope it'll work

```
<Formik
  initialValues={{
    firstName: "",
    lastName: "",
    email: "",
    Password: "",
    ConfirmPassword: "",
  }}
  validationSchema={SignupSchema}
  onSubmit={async (values) => {
    console.log("logging click");
    const {
      firstName,
      lastName,
      email,
      Password,
      ConfirmPassword,
    } = values;

    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("firstName", firstName);
    formData.append("lastName", lastName);
    formData.append("email", email);
    formData.append("Password", Password);
    formData.append("ConfirmPassword", ConfirmPassword);

    try {
      const res = await axios.post(
        "http://localhost:8080/api/artist",
        formData,
        {
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
          },
        }
      );
      console.log(res);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }}
>
```

For your reference, you can go to your browser developer console and visit the network tab while making a post request. If there is more than one request, it indicates that your code is making redundant requests.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you have nested event listeners and some unnecessary code in your form submission handling, which might be causing the issue. Here's a simplified version of how you can send form data to the backend using Axios and Formik: